# T SQL SSMS Convert Varchar DD\MM\YYYY to Date format

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms, ssms-2014

I have a `VARCHAR(10)` data type column with date in `DD\MM\YYYY` format.
I tried using `convert(datetime,LOCALDATE_T,103)` and much more. However throws me an error of

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I am unsure if my query could read `DD\MM\YYYY`. I have usually converted column from `DD/MM/YYYY` format i.e. `/` but not this `\`

Request your assistance.

Comment: REPLACE(mydatetextfield, '\', '/')

Comment: *DON'T* store dates as strings. This is a crime against humanity. Use the `date` type

Comment: For example, you can't query for dates before, after or between other dates because strings are sorted alphabetically. You can't use an index on this colun. Casting will allow you to query but force a *FULL TABLE SCAN*. It's essentially useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working solution is:

```
CONVERT(datetime, REPLACE(LOCALDATE_T, '\', '/'), 103)
```

or

```
CAST(REPLACE(LOCALDATE_T, '\', '/') as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) instead of CONVERT Function

```
 REPLACE(LOCALDATE_T,'\','/')
```